# Root or zero...which to use when?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, terminology, roots

This may seem like a very basic question, but:

What exactly is the difference between a root of a polynomial, and a zero?  Of course I realise that they are technically exactly the same thing, but there seem to be subtle rules as to when to use each term, and a couple of times in the past I have been told I am using "root" where I should be using "zero".

Is it generally accepted that one should use "root" in an algebraic context,  and "zero" in a analytic context? If not, when should one use one or the other...and does it really matter?!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference is the following: whenever you have a *function* $f:X\to \mathbb R$ you say that $x^*$ is a *zero* of $f$ if $f(x^*) = 0$. On the other hand, the same $x^*$ is a *root* of *the equation* $f(x) = 0$. The rule of thumbs: zero refers to the function (e.g. polynomial) and root refers to the equation.

Comment: I've often heard the two terms used interchangeably, though. "Roots of the polynomial $x^3+x-1$" isn't something I'd be surprised to hear a professional mathematician say.

Answer (score 8):

In general we will find zero of a function root of an equation

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I realize you don't yet have enough reputation, but this would have been better as a comment. Regards

Answer (score 2):

The difference is better seen on an equation with a nonzero right side:

$$f(x)=g(x)$$

The possible solutions of this equation are its roots. They are found at the intersection of the graphs:

[image]

Each functions has possibly its own zeros, which are the x-intercepts. So *root* relates to an equation and *zero* relates to a function.

With a zero right side:

$$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=0$$

The zeros of $h(x)$ are also the roots of $h(x)=0$:

[image]

In the case of $h(x)=0$, we may see $0$ as a constant function $z(x)=0$ (where any $x$ is a zero of $z$), and the roots are still the intersections of two graphs.

As for the roots of a polynomial $P(x)$, they are the solutions of the equation $P(x)=0$. More generally root is synonymous to solution to an equation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "root" in Australia. It has a [very](http://www.koalanet.com.au/australian-slang.html#R) different meaning.

Comment: Wouldn't this answer be better as a comment?

Comment: @lhf, you have a point. I figure the question was, in part, "when should you use 'root'" and I figure that "not in Australia" is a (partial) answer to that question. I don't see where any harm is done by posting it as an answer rather than as a comment. And there is the advantage that you can't vote down a comment.

Comment: Thanks Gerry.  So in Australia, the root of a polynomial is considered to be a deviant act, as opposed to a mathematical object?  I'll keep this in mind when I'm next there.

Comment: Absolutely useless contribution