# Difference between root, zero and solution.

Tags: terminology

Can somebody precisely tell me what is the difference between  a root, a zero and solution ?

Is it correct to say that an equation has solutions, and a polynomial has zeros or roots?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82643/root-or-zero-which-to-use-when

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my interpretation.

The word **solution** is used in the following context. Find the **solution** to $$f(x) = b \tag{$\star$},$$ where $f: A \mapsto B$, i.e., find the set of all $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = b$.

The **zeros** of the function $f$ is the set of all $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = 0_B$, where $0_B$ is the zero element in $B$. Hence, **zeros** are used specifically in the context when the $b$ in $(\star)$ is $0_B$. To see it in a slightly different way, the **zeros** of $g(x)$, where $$g(x) = f(x)-b$$ are the **solutions** to the equation $f(x) = b$.

The term **roots** are typically used to describe the zeros of a function, when the function $f(x)$ is of the following form: $f: R \mapsto R$, where $R$ is a ring. I believe, the usage was due to the fact that we talk about finding the square roots, cube roots, etc, which was then extended to polynomials and thereby extended to rings.

Comment: (+1): I think you mean "$a\in A$ such that $f(a)=0_B$", perhaps.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks. Updated.

Comment: The term 'root' is often used to describe a solution to an equation.  Consider the `Roots` function in Mathematica.  In contrast, Maple's `Roots` function matches the definition here.  It is unclear to me that there is a canonical definition.  If so, I'd like that to be documented.

Answer (score 4):

If we're talking about an equation, a root and a solution are synonymous.

If we're talking about a function, a root and a zero are synonymous.