# Definition of equation vs. expression vs. polynomial in the context of zeros vs. roots

Tags: functions, polynomials, terminology, roots

I was trying to figure out the distinction of a **root** and a **zero** and found people in such discussions make distinctions between **equation** vs. **expression** vs. **polynomial** without defining them.  What is the difference exactly?

I'm especially confused by function.  Likely I've forgotten many details from my high school math such as this definition.  I can tell you about functions in several programming languages, but that's not the same thing at all.

So are root and zero the same things or are they applied to different things?   Interestingly two of the suggested links for this question were "Roots of Polynomial Equation?" and "Finding the zeros of a polynomial equation."

Comment: Weird, I can add a comment here, but not in other questions...  The thread I am referred to talks about having zeros of functions and roots of an equation, but fails to show the distinction.  It would seem the difference is the equation does not require a zero on the RHS while the example does have a zero RHS muddying the explanation.  So that is the real difference.  If the RHS is zero, the two are equivalent and so explains why the terms are commingled.  But the root does not imply the RHS is zero and so they can be different.

Comment: The thread was closed claiming this thread already answered the question.  It does answer part, but not the actual question I asked, which was about the targets of application of the root and zero rather than the terms themselves. The thread below does not do a good job of answering the question I asked.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82643/root-or-zero-which-to-use-when  The answer to this question does a much better job of answering what I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A polynomial is a linear combination of natural powers of the variable. E.g.

$$ax^2+bx+c.$$

An expression is a series of symbols that can be evaluated (this is a very general term). E.g.

$$\sin(x).$$

(A polynomial is an expression; the converse is not necessarily true.)

An equation is an equality relation between two expressions. E.g.

$$ax^2+bx+c=\sin(x).$$
An equation can be polynomial or not.

A zero is a value of an unknown that makes an expression vanish, i.e. it is a solution of an equation with a zero RHS. E.g. $x$ such that

$$ax^2+bx+c=0.$$

A root is a value that satisfies an equation. E.g. $x$ such that

$$ax^2+bx+c=\sin(x).$$

Comment: in case of polynomial, finite is implied in linear combination